# Recycler View gets loaded again when switching between fragments

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-fragmentactivity

So, I have an activity which contains three fragments and I am switching between the fragments using ViewPager.

So in one of my Fragment I am using a recycler view to load my data. I am using onCreateView to initialize my view and populate recycler view also. But the problem here is when I switch back and forth between the fragments my recycler view items gets loaded again. I don't want that. I want the items to be loaded only once.

eg. when I switch back and forth between IMAGES and SAVED tab the recycler view gets reloaded in IMAGES tab.(ps. look at image to understand better)
[image: my fragments view]

This is my fragment where recycler view is loaded.

```
public ImageFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    statusView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image,container,false);
    initViews();
    return statusView;
}

private void initViews() {
    progressBar = statusView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    recyclerView = statusView.findViewById(R.id.statusRecyclerView);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new ListViewItemDecorator(getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.spacing)));
    refreshLayout = statusView.findViewById(R.id.statusSwipeRefreshLayout);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    adapter = new StatusAdapter(getContext(),arrayList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),2));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    recyclerView.scheduleLayoutAnimation();
}
```

So is there anyway to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ViewPager2 to create a tab bar that will solve your problem.